# 3D accelerator ATI Mobility Radeon HD5470

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, hardware-acceleration

I've got an ATI Mobility Radeon HD5470 on my laptop running on Ubuntu with windows 7 as guest on VMware.

In order to run games etc I need 3D acceleration activated on VMware. I tried installing the ATI drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 LTE but when I did that my screen was black and had to reinstall Ubuntu.

How can I get 3D acceleration working on VMware?

Used this command /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

and results were:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

And Accelerate 3D graphics checkbox on VMware is checked. 
But without result. I'm clueless at the moment...

[image]

Also this is what I'm getting when I try to run Solitair:

[image]

This is what VMware shows when I turn on the engine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VMWare places it's own video driver into Ubuntu - the ATI driver that you added will not help.  In the VMWare menu for settings on your virtual machine, there should be a display option under the hardware tab, and in the display settings an 'Accelerate 3D graphics' checkbox.

Comment: That checkbox is checked. But it doesn't work. Somehow I need to do something else to get it to work.

Comment: Oh, I've also ran the command man Radeon and according to that my card does support 3D acceleration. So it's not that my card's not good enough for it.

Comment: Ah.  VMWare does need the host machine to support 3D...

Comment: Yeah, that's true. And the host does support it. Somehow VMware doesn't recoqnize it that the host supports it

Comment: If you can find the VMWare config files (I don't know where they are in Windows) there is a line which reads 'mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = FALSE` = Change it to `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE`  The file in Linux is `~/.vmware/preferences` -> this should be done on the host, not the client.

Comment: My host is Linux and does have everything enabled. Check the results above......

Comment: Ah - I was dealing with another person, similar issue.  That's what I get for not reading closely.

Comment: Haha no problem man :) it's appreciated. Do you have a clue for me?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have the `blacklist` entry already done, and your host is running GL properly, I'm not sure what to do.  I use an Intel card myself, and it's been off and on since 12.04, but 14.10 is working pretty well for me.